# ActiveMQ - Transactional session NOT commit all messages

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm working with ActiveMQ for implement a JMS system.
My first scenario works properly using a NOT transacted session, like this:

```
connection.createQueueSession(false, ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

After, I need a redelivery system, so I've read that the redelivery options works by default using a transacted session (http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html), so I change my code:

```
connection.createQueueSession(true, ActiveMQSession.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
```

And I've change the send and the onMessage methods.
Both methods share the same session, so the methods became like this:

SendMethod:

```
public static ObjectMessage createObjectMessageAndSendIt(Serializable toSend) throws JMSException {
    ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
    message.setObject(toSend);
    sender.send(message);
    commitSession();
    return message;
}
```

OnMessage method:

```
public void onMessage(Message m) {
    LOG.debug("IN onMessage message with ID [" + m.getJMSMessageID() + "]");
    try {
        if (m != null) {
            if (m instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                // do something
                m.acknowledge();
                JMSUtils.commitSession();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Rollback session because this message must be redelivered, it will be sent to DLQ
        JMSUtils.rollbackSession();
    }

    LOG.debug("OUT onMessage message with ID [" + m.getJMSMessageID() + "]");
}
```

All works good when I send a single message, but when I start massive send of message, at the end there are some messages that remain into the queue though they are correctly elaborated. This situation cause, that at the new start of the server, this message will be elaborated a second time (I use persistence into KahaDB).

Could you suggest me why there are this strange situation?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seams that using the same Session for Sender and Consumer generate my problem.
In fact, now I try to use separate session

- after send I commit the sender session
- in consumer I commit or rollback the consumerSession

and all works as excepted.

If I'm doing something wrong or you've other suggestions please reply to me.